# IE7 : <ul> disappearing on hover

Tags: internet-explorer-7, hover, position, absolute

Having a very strange IE7 issue that I cannot find a fix for. I have created a slideshow with a control nav absolutely positioned at the bottom of it. The nav sits over the slideshows bottom border.

In ie7, hovering over it cause the nav to jump behind the border and hence the top of it disappears. I don't have a clue what is happening and cannot find solutions elsewhere. Here is a link demonstrating the issue:

http://rivaslider.matthewruddy.com/

Anyone have a solution? Pulling my hair out.